# Elastic search to be deployed as embedded or client/server mode

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

Which is the preferred mode of deployment for Elasticsearch, embedded mode (embedded in to the product/application) or client/server mode?

Apache Solr and most of the SQL, NOSQL databases are usually deployed in client/server mode. Where server runs as standalone, the client might be a driver library which will be used in the application.

In case of Elasticsearch, client and server binaries are the same. It would be difficult to package two separate Elasticsearch binaries, one for client to use in the application and another for the standalone server. I am planning to go with Rest API because I cannot package two set of Elasticsearch binaries in my product.

What is the general practice for Elasticsearch deployment? Keep Elasticsearch as standalone and use Rest API or embedded Elasticsearch within the application?

Answer (score 0):

For production usage it is better to decouple your application from elasticsearch srever.
Lets say you want to upgrade to elastic 2.X that mean that you will need to re-compile your application - wouldnt it be overhead?

If you to run unit/data integration test you can use elasticsearch as embedded service to your testing needs